# Can we execute sql query on remote machine without logging in

Tags: mysql, sql

If my box ip is 10.10.10.10, is it possible to execute some sql suery like

```
select * from some_table
```

on remote machine 10.10.10.20 without logging into that machine from terminal
If not, when is it possible

Comment: Yes, this is possible. MySQL implements a client/server architecture. What is your concrete issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible using the MySQL client. You can either use this syntax:

```
mysql -u <username> -p -h remote.host database -e 'show databases;'
```

or use pass in a script file:

```
mysql -u <username> -p -h remote.host database < script.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  You have not told us what your setup is.  If you are *not* using a programming language already, see @Jaco's answer.  If you are using a programming language, then in your connection string, you replace `localhost` (or `10.10.10.10`) with `10.10.10.20`.

Answer (score 0):

If mysql on `10.10.10.10` has networking enabled (by default it is only enabled for local communications, you should enable listening on 0.0.0.0 in config) and port 3306 is open on firewall, you can.

Add a user, that is permitted to connect to mysql remotely from 10.10.10.20 (i.e. username@'10.10.10.20' or username@'%'), then just do

```
mysql -u username -p -h 10.10.10.10 your_database_name
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to connect with your remote database no matter where it is located (even for local databases) by providing the server location/url, DB name, user name and the password (in some cases you need to give the port name also). the exact coding you need to use to create the connection differs slightly based on the language you are working with. Once you have a working DB connection with you, you can execute any sql query that is permitted for the logged in user.

- If you want to connect from a remote location, the DB user should have privileges to connect remotely. ("%" is used to allow from any location).

  ```
  CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';

  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'%';
  ```
- if you want to connect from the terminal ;

  ```
    shell> mysql -h 10.10.10.10  -u newuser -pmypass mydb
  ```